# Changing exit transformation on ordinal Axis

Tags: d3.js

Here's a simple example of the axis transition effects as you sort an ordinal scale. This works really well when you click 'swap item'. When the change in data includes new items or removes items, the default behavior to to fade them in and out. You can see this behavior in the snippet when you click 'change items'

This is sensible and it works for most situations. But I would like to perform a different animation when new items enter and leave the axis - for example have removed items transition off the bottom of the axis and new ones slide up. I can't figure where to hook in code that allows the behavior of existing elements to continue while changing the fade-in/fade-out effect on added and removed items.

How would one do this?

```js
var fruit1 = [
    ['Apple', 10],
    ['Orange', 15],
    ['Bananas', 7],
    ['Kiwi', 11],
    ['Mangosteen', 3],
    ['Sapodilla', 9]
  ],
  fruit2 = [
    ['Bananas', 7],
    ['Kiwi', 11],
    ['Mangosteen', 3],
    ['Sapodilla', 9],
    ['Durian', 11],
    ['Jack Fruit', 2]
  ],
  toggle = false;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 60,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 170
  },
  width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .padding([0.1]),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)

function update(data) {
  y.domain(data.map(d => d[0]))

  svg.select('.y')
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(yAxis)
}

function swap() {
  d = toggle ? fruit2 : fruit1
  for (let i = d.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [d[i - 1], d[j]] = [d[j], d[i - 1]];
  }
  update(d)
}

function change() {
  d = toggle ? fruit1 : fruit2
  toggle = !toggle
  update(d)
}

update(fruit1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<button onclick="swap()">Swap Items</button>
<button onclick="change()">Change Items</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js#L78) the transition is baked in and I can't see a way to modify it.